# React leaflet WMSTileLayer with custom request headers

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to send authentication header with my wms tile requests.
When I used pure leaflet library it was very simple using leaflet-wms-header
But, I have switched to react-leaflet and it has its own WMSTileLayer component. How can I solve my problem and send a header with every tile img request?